What separation axioms are held by Gustin's sequence space?
Gustin's sequence space is defined as counterexample #125 in Steen and Seebach's Counterexamples in Topology. Notably, while most of its separation axioms are established in its General Reference Chart (it is $T_2$ but not $T_3$ nor functionally Hausdorff), it's left open whether this space is $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ (points are separated by open sets with disjoint closures) or semi-regular (the space has a basis of regular open sets, open sets that equal the interiors of their closures).
Is this space $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ and/or semi-regular?

The task may be made somewhat easier given a less cludgy definition for the space than was provided in Counterexamples (and without the errata that are currently present in $\pi$-Base). Let $\omega=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$, let $Y=(\omega^2)^{<\omega}$ be the set of finite sequences of $\omega$ of even length, let $Y_i=\{s\in Y:\forall k<|s|(s(k)\geq i)\}$, and let $X=Y\cup(\omega\times[Y]^2)$ where and $[Y]^2$ is the collection of size-two subsets of $Y$. Let $t^\frown s$ be the concatentation of finite sequences $t,s$.
Given a point $t\in Y$, let it have neighborhoods of the form $$U_i(t)=\{t^\frown s\in Y:s\in Y_i\}.$$
Given a point $\langle n,W\rangle\in \omega\times[Y]^2$, first let $q:\omega\times[Y]^2\to\omega$ be an injection that's increasing on $\omega$, that is, $q(n+1,W)>q(n,W)$ for $n<\omega$ and $W\in[Y]^2$, for example let $p:W\to \mathbb{N}_+$ be injection into prime numbers and $q(n, w) = (p(w))^n$.
Finally, give $\langle n,W\rangle$ neighborhoods of the form $$V_i(n,W)=\{\langle n,W\rangle\}\cup \bigcup_{w\in W,j\geq i}U_i(w^\frown \langle q(n,W),j\rangle).$$

Note that the requirement in Counterexamples in Topology that $Y$ consists of finite sequences of even length, and not just finite sequences, is needed to show that this space is Hausdorff.

Thanks Jakobian! I think I've corrected my characterization above (and should fix my answer below to match).

I'll be using definition of Gustin's sequence space as the space #125 of Counterexamples in topology.
That is space $X = Y\cup (\mathbb{N}_+\times W)$ where $Y$ consists of even-length finite sequences of positive natural numbers, $W$ consists of unordered pairs from $Y$ (subsets of size $2$), $q:\mathbb{N}_+\times W\to \mathbb{N}_+$ assigns to each pair $(n, w)$ a number $q(n, w) = p(w)^n$ where $p(w)$ is prime and $p:W\to\mathbb{N}_+$ is injective.
If $\alpha, \beta$ are any sequences of positive natural numbers, $\alpha\beta$ where we first list elements of $\alpha$ and then elements of $\beta$. The notation $\alpha\subseteq_i \beta$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}_+$ means that $\beta = \alpha\gamma$ for some finite sequence $\gamma$ where every element of the sequence $\gamma$ is $\geq i$. If there exists $\gamma$ such that $\beta = \alpha\gamma$, I will say $\beta$ extends $\alpha$.
Define $U_i(\alpha) = \{\beta\in Y : \alpha\subseteq_i \beta\}$, $V_i(n, w) = \{(n, w)\}\cup U_i(\alpha q(n, w))\cup U_i(\beta q(n, w))$ where $w = \{\alpha, \beta\}$ and $Z(i, \gamma) = \{(n, w) : (\gamma\subseteq_i \alpha q(n, w)\text{ or }\gamma\subseteq_i \beta q(n, w)), w = \{\alpha, \beta\}\}$ where $\gamma\in Y$.
We define $U_i(\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in Y$ and $V_i(n, w)$ for $(n, w)\in\mathbb{N}_+\times W$ to be a basis of open sets for $X$.
By item #2 of space #125 in Counterexamples in topology we have $\overline{U_i(\gamma)} = U_i(\gamma)\cup Z(i, \gamma)$ for $\gamma\in Y$.
First we'll prove $X$ is not semi-regular.
Suppose that $w = \{\gamma, \gamma ii\}$ and $n$ is large enough so that $q(n, w) = p(w)^n \geq i$. Then $\gamma \subseteq_i \gamma q(n, w)$, since its clear that $\gamma q(n, w)$ extends $\gamma$ and $q(n, w)\geq i$. So $(n, w)\in Z(i, \gamma)$. Moreover if $\alpha\in U_i(\gamma q(n, w))$ then $\alpha$ extends $\gamma q(n, w)$, and so it extends $\gamma$, where terms after $\gamma q(n, w)$ are all $\geq i$, and the term $q(n, w)\geq i$ as well, so $\alpha\in U_i(\gamma)$. And if $\alpha\in U_i(\gamma ii q(n, w))$ then by the exact same argument $\alpha$ extends $\gamma$ with all the terms after $\gamma$ being $\geq i$, so that again $\alpha\in U_i(\gamma)$. This shows that $V_i(n, w)\subseteq \overline{U_i(\gamma)}$ and so $\left(\mathbb{N}_+\times W\right)\cap \text{int}(\overline{U_i(\gamma)}) \neq \emptyset$.
If now $\gamma\in U\subseteq Y$ where $U$ is open (note that $Y$ is open), then $U_i(\gamma)\subseteq U$ for some $i$, so that $\text{int}(\overline{U})\supseteq \text{int}(\overline{U_i(\gamma)})$ so that $\text{int}(\overline{U})\cap (\mathbb{N}_+\times W)\neq \emptyset$ and so $U$ is not a regular open set.
It follows that $X$ cannot admit a basis of regular open sets, since there is no non-empty regular open set contained in $Y$. Thus $X$ is not semi-regular.

Gustin's sequence space is also not $T_{2.5}$. To see this, note that for any two non-empty open sets $U_1, U_2$ of $X$, we can find non-empty open sets $U_i(\gamma)\subseteq U_1$ and $U_j(\delta)\subseteq U_2$ where $\gamma, \delta\in Y$. From item #2 again, we have $\overline{U_i(\gamma)}\cap \overline{U_j(\delta)}\supseteq Z(i, \gamma)\cap Z(j, \delta)$.
But now like in item #3 for this space, $Z(i, \gamma)\cap Z(j, \delta)$ is non-empty, and in fact its infinite. For if $(n, w)$ where $w = \{\alpha, \beta\}$ is such that $q(n, w) > \max(i, j)$ and $\gamma\subseteq_i \alpha, \delta\subseteq_i \beta$ then $(n, w)\in Z(i, \gamma)\cap Z(j, \delta)$, but there exists infinitely many points which satisfy this.
This shows that $\overline{U_1}\cap \overline{U_2}$ must be infinite, so cannot possibly be non-empty.

As another corollary of this property, if $F\subseteq X$ is any finite set, then $X\setminus F$ is connected. For if $X\setminus F$ could be written as union of two non-empty disjoint open sets $U_1, U_2$, then $\overline{U_1}\cap\overline{U_2}\subseteq F$ which is impossible.

It's observed in point #3 of space #125 in Counterexamples that the closures of any two open sets have non-empty intersection. It immediately follows that this space cannot be $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$.
To elaborate: $$cl(U_i(t))=U_i(t)\cup\{\langle n,W\rangle:\exists w\in W\,\exists s\in Y_i\,(t^\frown s=w^\frown \langle q(n,W),i\rangle)\}.$$
Then given $U_{i_0}(t_0),U_{i_1}(t_1)$, let $W=\{t_0,t_1\}$ and pick $n<\omega$ such that $q(n,W)\geq\max(i_0,i_1)$. Then $\langle n,W\rangle\in cl(U_{i_b}(t_b))$ for $b\in\{0,1\}$: choose $w=t_b\in W$ and $s=\langle q(n,W),i_b\rangle\in Y_{i_b}$, so $t_b\,^\frown s=w^\frown\langle q(n,W),i\rangle$.
Finally, I will show that the interior of the closure of any basic open neighborhood $U_i(\langle\rangle)$ of $\langle\rangle\in Y$ is not contained in $U_i(\langle\rangle)$, demonstrating that the space is not semi-regular. Note that $$U_i(\langle\rangle)=Y_i$$ and $$cl(U_i(\langle\rangle))=Y_i\cup\{\langle n,W\rangle:\exists w\in W\,\exists s\in Y_i\,(s=w^\frown \langle q(n,W),i\rangle)\}$$ $$=Y_i\cup\{\langle n,W\rangle:w\in Y_i,q(n,W)\geq i\}.$$
Pick $W=\{\langle\rangle,\langle i,i\rangle\}$ and pick $n<\omega$ such that $q(n,W)\geq i$. Then $$V_i(n,W)=\{\langle n,W\rangle\}\cup \bigcup_{j\geq i} U_i(\langle q(n,W),j\rangle)\cup \bigcup_{j\geq i}U_i(\langle i,i,q(n,W),j\rangle)$$ $$\subseteq\{\langle n,W\rangle\} \cup Y_i\subseteq cl(U_i(\langle\rangle))$$ and therefore $\langle n,W\rangle\in int(cl(U_i(\langle\rangle)))\setminus U_i(\langle\rangle)$.
